# Time-series analysis, resetting time to 0

Tags: python, time, analysis

I am currently working on a time-based dataset. I have cleaned the dataset by removing zeros at the beginning and end of my dataset. Now instead of starting from 0, the time for my dataset starts at 7000s - 400000s. I would like to make the starting time (7000s) to 0 and from then increases.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share a snap of you data?

Comment: subtract 7000 seconds from all elements in your x (time) vector? honestly, I think you'll need to provide more information how your data looks like and what specific problem you're trying to solve how.